# HTML Navigation bar off center in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have tested my website in both Chrome, Firefox and mobile browsers and it appears correctly, however in IE 11 and below, it doesn't. How can I fix this? I tried looking through for anything IE is incompatible with, and to my knowledge I didn't see anything,

This is what is giving me trouble

```css
header {
  background-image: url(../Images/Noise.png);
  /*background-color: rgb(160, 160, 160);*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center
}
header > nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: none;
  flex: 1;
  transform: 300ms all ease
}
header nav > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px
}
header nav > ul > li {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  position: relative;
  margin: auto
}
header nav > ul > li.Main {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #6495ED;
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 120px;
  margin: auto
}
}
header nav > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 250ms all ease
}
header nav > ul > li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: none
}
header nav > ul > li > a span.toggle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  border-radius: 3rem;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  font-size: .75em;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  text-transform: lowercase
}
header nav > ul > li > a span.caret {
  display: none
}
header > nav > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #8cc1c1
}
header > nav > ul > li > nav {
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  z-index: 100
}
header > nav > ul > li > nav > ul > li > a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  transition: 300ms all ease
}
header > nav > ul > li > nav > ul > li:hover > a {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)
}
header > div#logo {
  line-height: 70px;
  position: relative
}
header > div#logo > h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300
}
header > div#logo > div#navToggle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 300ms all ease
}
header > div#logo > div#navToggle:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}
header > div#logo > div#navToggle > a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
  display: block;
  font-size: .85em;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0 2.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 300ms all ease
}
header > div#logo > div#navToggle:hover > a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="menuUp" id="logo">
    <iframe align="left" class="clock" frameborder="no" id="clock" name="clock" scrolling="no" src="http://www.clocklink.com/html5embed.php?clock=004&timezone=local&color=red&size=120&Title=&Message=&Target=&From=2015,1,1,0,0,0&Color=red" style="overflow:hidden;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;width:120px;height:40px;">
    </iframe>

    <h1>Justin's World</h1>
  </div>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="Main">
        <a href="Main.html">Home</a>
      </li>

      <li class="Main">
        <a href="Index/about.html">About</a>
      </li>

      <li class="Main">
        <a href="#">More</a>

        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="Index/art.html">Art</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="Index/blog.html">Blog</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="Index/gaming.html">Gaming</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="Index/humor.html">Humor</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="Index/Music.html">Music</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="Index/tutorials.html">Tutorials</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="Index/twitch.html">Twitch</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwplUoL-oEHoz5QqjtnOjrA">
                                Youtube</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: validate your css - namely line 13 and 35

Comment: Apart from the CSS itself (and  a couple of errors in it), are you sure you're not running your page in a legacy document mode?

Comment: to add to @Teemu's comment - use F12 when running your code in IE to verify. It should show under the Emulation tab

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? It seems to work the same for me in Firefox as in IE11.

Comment: To reiterate, what I mean by doesn't work, I mean the navbar shows up off center, the last one I have to scroll to access

Comment: I am not running my page in a legacy doc mode, and I have it in the default "edge" mode, switching to 10 does nothing, 9 stacks the options on top of each other, anything below that the buttons don't follow the CSS rules, and the buttons on the submenu are shown on the page.